# Is it possible to invalidate user's JWT on other devices?

Tags: jwt, invalidation

My App only allows user to login on one device at a time.  And I would like to use JWT.

Is it possible to invalidate the other JWT on devices other than the one I'm on?  without storing extra information in DB / cache (e.g. storing active user's JWT).

Answer (score 0):

After weeks of investigation and trying, I confirm there is no way to invalidate the other JWT without DB. the final solution is to store every JWT in DB (Redis). When validating JWT, not just check the token itself, also check if it exists in the DB